# not able to execute lighthouse command from Java

Tags: java, lighthouse

I am trying to execute lighthouse command from java. I am getting exit value 127(Command not found). Same command if I execute from terminal, it is working.

Code:

```
 Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
   String Command="lighthouse https://www.google.com/ --output=json,html";                  
   Process proc = rt.exec(command);
   proc.waitFor();              
   int e=proc.exitValue();
   StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
   InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
  String line = "";                       
  while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) 
  {
     output.append(line + "\n");
   }
  System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: Try using the full path to lighthouse

Comment: Lighthouse installed globally using command "npm install -g lighthouse"

Comment: I can't be precise about this as i don't know the software, but afaics it runs on Node.js(?) If so, that's what the shell should really be running, along with lighthouse as an argument to it. Presumably if you opened *an ordinary terminal* and tried to execute `lighthouse` it wouldn't know what you're talking about would it?

Comment: @g00se I am able to execute commands on terminal.

Comment: Which terminal are you using?

Comment: Mac Os terminal

Comment: Right. Please post (as *text*) output of `which lighthouse`